# How to create JsonArray and JsonObject in JsonObject java

Tags: java, arrays, json

How to create JsonArray and JsonObject in JsonObject

```
{
  "users": [7, 16, 35],
  "group_id": "askskdjejs139d.."
}
```

Thank for your help :)

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ  i edited a topic post ,sorry

Comment: The docs show you how to build http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html have you tried to do it yet?

Comment: Which JSON library/package are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code:

```
JSONObject user1 = new JSONObject();
try {
    user1.put("user_id", "7");
    user1.put("group_id", "askskdjejs139d");


} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JSONObject user2 = new JSONObject();
try {
    user2.put("user_id", "16");
    user2.put("group_id", "askskdjejs139d");


} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}


JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

jsonArray.put(user1);
jsonArray.put(user2);

JSONObject userObj = new JSONObject();
    userObj.put("Users", jsonArray);



String jsonStr = userObj.toString();

    System.out.println("jsonString: "+jsonStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using **`org.json`** Library.

### Given below are some examples:

```
// Creating a json object
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

// Adding elements to json object
jsonObj.put("key", "value"); // the value can also be a json object or a json array

// Creating a json object from an existing json string
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("Your json string");

// Creating a json array
JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();

// Adding a json object to json object to json Array
jsonArray.add(jsonObj);

// Adding json array as an element of json object
jsonObject.put("key", "<jsonArray>");
```

You can call `toString()` method of `JsonObject` or `JsonArray` to get the `String` representation of the json object/array.